# Object of class Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I am sending mail from the controller. mail is also sent successfully but it gives me one error in laravel.log file. log trace is below

```
[2023-03-10 13:01:56] local.ERROR: Object of class Illuminate\Mail\SentMessage could not be converted to string {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Object of class Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage could not be converted to string at 
C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\Logger.php:265)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\Logger.php(182): Illuminate\\Log\\Logger->formatMessage(Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage))
#1 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\Logger.php(130): Illuminate\\Log\\Logger->writeLog('info', Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage), Array)
#2 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager.php(686): Illuminate\\Log\\Logger->info(Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage), Array)
#3 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\helpers.php(490): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->info(Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage), Array)
#4 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\app\\Jobs\\ProcessReport.php(99): info(Object(Illuminate\\Mail\\SentMessage))
#5 C:\\wamp64\\www\\cis\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Jobs\\ProcessReport->handle()
```

This is my controller code

```
$data['user_id'] = $request['user_id'];
$data['tenant'] = $request['stenant'];
$data['folder'] = $request['time'];
$report = Report::create($data);
Mail::to($request['semail'])->send(new ReportGenerated($report));
```

and below is my ReportGenerated mail class

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Models\Report;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Content;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Envelope;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ReportGenerated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public function __construct(
        public Report $report,
    ) {}

    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: 'Report Generated',
        );
    }

    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'emails.report',
            with: [
                'tenant' => $this->report->tenant,
            ],
        );
    }

    public function attachments(): array
    {
        $tenant_val = explode('.',$this->report->tenant);
        return [
            Attachment::fromPath(storage_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "app" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "public" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "reports" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $tenant_val[0] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->report->folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "final.pdf")
                ->as('report.pdf')
                ->withMime('application/pdf'),
        ];
    }
}
```

I don't know from where this log is generated?

Comment: Your background job `App\Jobs\ProcessReport` might be the culprit. The log is generated by that Job class.

Comment: In `app\\Jobs\\ProcessReport.php(99)` you probably want to `debug::info()` something, but you're sending your entire class to that info function. The problem is that it's hard to guess without seeing the code, can you post that code in your original question